# Calculate a confusion matrix given two matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, confusion-matrix

I have two Xval(Predicted values) and Sv(validation test) matrices, one with the classifier output data and the other with the validation data for the same samples. Each column represents the predicted value, eg [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] represents digit 3 (1 in the digit that is). I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the confusion matrix in a vectorized way or with a built in function, the sizes of both matrices are 12000x10. The code who generates both matrices are this

```
load data;
load test;
[N, m] = size(X);
X = [ones(N, 1) X];
[Nt, mt] = size(Xt);
Xt = [ones(Nt, 1) Xt];
new_order = randperm(N);
X = X(new_order,: );
S = S(new_order,: );
part = 0.8;
Xtr = X(1: (part * N),: );
Xv = X((part * N + 1): N,: );
Str = S(1: (part * N),: );
Sv = S((part * N + 1): N,: );
v_c = [];
v_tx_acerto = [];
tx_acerto_max = 0;
c =  250;
w = (X'*X+c*eye(m+1))\X' * S; 
Xval = Xv*w;
for i=1:12000
    aux = Xval(i,:);
    aux(aux == max(aux)) = 1;
    aux(aux<1) = 0;
    Xval(i,:) = aux;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are build-in functions [confusionmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html) or [plotconfusion](https://de.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/plotconfusion.html). But if you want to have full control, you can just write a simple function yourself, e.g:

```
function [CMat_rel,CMat_abs] = ConfusionMatrix(Cprd,Cact)

Cprd_uq = unique(Cprd);
Cact_uq = unique(Cact);

NumPrd = length(Cprd_uq);
NumAct = length(Cact_uq);
% assert(NumPrd == NumAct)

% allocate memory
CMat_abs = NaN(NumPrd,NumAct);
CMat_rel = NaN(NumPrd,NumAct);
for j = 1:NumAct
    lgAct = Cact == Cact_uq(j);
    SumAct = sum(lgAct);
    for i = 1:NumAct
        lgPrd = Cprd == Cact_uq(i);

        Num = sum( lgPrd(lgAct) == true );
        CMat_abs(i,j) = Num;
        CMat_rel(i,j) = Num/SumAct;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! but i want to compute a matrix like this, given 2 matrix of predicted and true.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYlBa.jpg like this!
On a vectorized way or using some built in function, thanks!

Comment: that is what the code does (assuming that you predict vectors). Otherwise, look at the build-in functions that I named ;)